# .htaccess - passing an URI argument instead of directory listing PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need a suggestion using `.htaccess` (I presume) or any other solution for the following situation:

On the server, for example I have a folder `www.mypage.com/accommodation/` which contains `index.php` script.

What I would like to do is that when the called URL is something like `www.mypage.com/accommodation/apartment-mike`   (note no / in the end or extension), that the string "`apartment-mike`" (`$_SERVER['request_uri']`) is passed to the `index.php` script in the accommodation folder instead of trying to directory walk apartment-mike directory.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: We've edited your post to be more standard to SO: note than using the `{}` button in the editor allows you to change format for code or technical terms.  
Please not also we prefer pragmatic question of people who tried to search more by themself: what is the problem you are facing? did you find any way by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must rewrite the call to `index.php`. This is a classic and can be found anywhere

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

The next step is accessing the URI itself, which you already figured yourself by using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Hi Mr. Dietsche, this works if I call www.mypage.com/accommodation/index.php/apartment-mike , with this same configuration , if I just type all of this without index.php, being www.mypage.com/accommodation/apartment-mike it still tries to directory list the apartment-mike and says the directory is not found. Rewrite engine is ON, mod rewrite is on. Additional suggestions?

Comment: Have you put the .htaccess file into the `accomodation` directory?

Comment: Yes...I managed to make it work with:RewriteRule .*$ index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file `apartment-mike.php`,  contains a ridirection to `index.php`, to the `accomodation` folder then add the following lines to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

to remove the extension from appearing in the uri
don't forget to add

```
header("location:index.php");
```

to the `apatement-mike.php` if you want it to pass users to the index

Comment: Hi Balgacem, unfortunately this will not help me, as I'm trying to load dynamic content based on the request_uri argument sent in the address bar. Meaning if accommodation/apartment_mike_3 I would query my db for the apartment_mike_3 and load it's data.

Comment: then for each apartment registration in the DB you need to create a file with its name, but with the less possible number of lines, where you include all of the header , body , footer  from external scripts and the `.htaccess` will avoid the file  extension

Comment: I have managed to resolve it being dynamic with RewriteRule .*$ index.php without using the DB.